# Python garbage collect in imap_unordered

Tags: python, garbage-collection, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

In common case work with pool, python marks returned args as deleted and gc within some time will delete this object from memory e.g.

```
def main():
    for x in pool.imap_unordered(func, args):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But how will be work garbage collector in case launch pool without accumulate result?

```
def main():
    pool.imap_unordered(func, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If pool works constantly, have any chance to get overload memory?

Comment: Hm, are the processes launched without iterating over the `imap`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way to iterate over generator without getting result is standard `for _ in map(): pass`, because Python will don't allocate new memory for each object in map generator and will set each object in one region.